# How show list title post by tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create custom page to show list title post by tag.

**Example:**

This title post by tag "handphone"

1. Title post
2. Title post
3. Title post
4. ...etc

*Any have code for this problem?*

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a template for your page 
write the postcode below into the template

```
<?php
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$args=array('posts_per_page'=>5, 'tag' => $brand_name);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) :
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  echo '<li>';
  the_title();
  echo '</li>';
  endwhile;
endif;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $original_query;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

after that assigne the template from admin end to your page and lets see it's wwork or not .

Answer (score 2):

Create a php file in your theme directory.  You can give any name. And use code something like this. Replate tag_name by your desire tag. And then create a page. Set the template. You will see the list.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Title by Tag
 *
 */
 get_header();

$args=array('posts_per_page'=>5, 'tag' => 'tag_name');
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) :
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
<li>
<?php the_title();  ?>
 </li> 
<?php
  endwhile;
endif;


wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create page and add below code to your page

```
   <?php
    /**
     * Template Name: Get title by tag
     *
     */
     get_header();

    $tagname = 'handphone';

    $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'post_type' => 'your-posttype', // or 'any'
       'tag_slug__in' => $tagname,
       'posts_per_page' => -1
    ));

    if ( have_posts() ) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
         the_title();  
      endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```